# ASP.NET C#: Create sub-folder in another website on same server

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I am in the need to create sub-folders within another website on the same server as the requesting website. How do I go about doing this?

I have tried Server.MapPath(path) but it is creating the folder within the current website.

I.E.:

websiteA on server 123 needs to create a directory within websiteB on server123.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set full path in order to do this, eg. c:\www\othersite\somefolder (for example you may set it as a configuration value in your web.config). Otherwise ASP.NET won't let you go above the root of your site.

However, I recommend to think twice about it, because it doesn't sound like a good pattern.

Comment: I tried to set the full path but I was being return an error of invalid virtual path. And this is for in house employees only so security of that is not of a big issue (we have massive audit trails for everything)

Comment: could you post your code? if you pass full path to standard io classes they don't do anything with virtual path